# Show the paused frame in the Android HTML5 player

Tags: javascript, android, html5-video

I'm creating a video player in HTML5 and JavaScript in which one has to step through frames paused at an accuracy of about *100ms*. I use the video time to display the specific frames. This player works on the computer and iPad-mini. However on the Android when I use the line:

```
video.currentTime = x
```

The HTML5 Android player moves the video, but does not show the frame content. The content only shows when the video plays! Could anyone help me with this?

Test it on your computer and android tablet/phone with the paused video:
http://codepen.io/KvByte/pen/wGXeYM

```html
<video id="video" controls="" preload="auto">
  <source src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
  <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
</video>

<br />

<button onclick="document.getElementById('video').currentTime-=3">currentTime-=3s</button>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('video').currentTime+=3">currentTime+=3s</button>
```

In Android, it moves the video but does not display the content!